# Ceiling fan wired for 4 way control?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I want to set up fan and light controls in three wall boxes, i.e. one fan/light control on each side of the bed, and one fan/light controller at the entrance to the room.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is your fan and light wired with 1 wall switch that controls both the fan and light, or with 2 wall switches that control the fan and light individually?

Comment: New construction so I asked for two switches for light and fan. But I see not one wire hanging down from box

Comment: are you talking about the switch box, or the fan box?

Comment: One fan and light on one side of bed, one fan and light switch on the other side of bed and ability to turn on fan and light at the entrance to the room. I prefer no remotes.

Comment: I mean -- which box are you referring to when you say "But I see not one wire hanging down from box"?

Comment: Ceiling where fan will go..sorry.

Comment: This is new construction? Why not just tell the guy you want this???

Comment: @SpeedyPetey -- I think that the asker doesn't know if it's even reasonable to ask her builder/electrician to do this to begin with!

Comment: ThreePhase. You are exactly correct!  Thanks so much for your solution!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using a multi-way fan/light controller system such as the [Lutron Maestro](http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Products/Pages/StandAloneControls/FanControls/Maestro/Overview.aspx) series.

You (or your electrician) will need a [MA-LFQM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MAVJZ8) package, which includes the master wall module and the canopy module, and two [MA-ALFQ35](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0039PZ5H6) accessory controls, as well as normal wiring supplies (two and three conductor cable of the appropriate gauge, wire nuts/connectors, etc).

The controls should be wired as per the diagram in step 12c of the [instructions](http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/033101a.pdf), and the canopy module as instructed.  Note that you can't mix standard three or four way switches with these controls as they use power-line communications between each other and the canopy module to provide speed control and dimming, and you also will no longer be able to use the pull chain controls on the fan.